# Lua5.3 vs Lua5.1 on the same code

Tags: lua

I have this script for factorial calculus in Lua:

```
N, F = 1, 1
while F < 1e200 do
print(N .. "! is " .. F)
N = N + 1
-- Compute the factorial of the new N based on
-- the factorial of the old N:
F = F * N
end
```

What's wrong with this code in Lua 5.3? After `19!` everything is weird.
But the same code works perfect in Lua 5.1.

Comment: Define "everything is weird"

Comment: In Lua5.3:
1! is 1

2! is 2

3! is 6

4! is 24

5! is 120

6! is 720

7! is 5040

8! is 40320

9! is 362880

10! is 3628800

11! is 39916800

12! is 479001600

13! is 6227020800

14! is 87178291200

15! is 1307674368000

16! is 20922789888000

17! is 355687428096000

18! is 6402373705728000

19! is 121645100408832000

20! is 2432902008176640000

21! is -4249290049419214848

22! is -1250660718674968576

23! is 8128291617894825984

24! is -7835185981329244160

Answer (score 2):

Lua 5.3 supports integers, which have wraparound arithmetic.

Try your code with

```
N, F = 1, 1.0
```

to get the same behavior as Lua 5.1.

Comment: Thank you lhf, that's what I was looking for!  I do not have much information about what is different in Lua5.3 vs 5.1

Comment: @costica_p, see http://www.lua.org/versions.html, http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/readme.html#changes and http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html#changes.

Comment: Floating points support much larger magnitudes then integers, so they will show problems (overflow or saturation) only for much larger values, although they will not have integer precision.